# Vue router: Route child carga el componente del padre

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
 {
    path: '/designblock',
    name: 'Design Block',
    component: Design,
    children: [
      {
         path: 'title',
         component: title,
      }
    ],
  },
```

Tengo esa ruta definida y al entrar `title` dicha ruta child me carga el componente `Design`

```
<router-link to="/designblock/title" class="design-card" exact>title<router-link>
```

La verdad no entiendo porque suele suceder esto

Comment: Hola, enséñanos un poco más de tu código. Simplemente con eso no podemos saber mas sobre tu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando tienes `children` en una ruta, siempre te va a cargar el componente padre, después va a buscar un `<router-view>` para cargar el componente hijo.

Si no quieres que te cargue el componente `Design` entonces declara tus rutas así:

```
{    
    path: '/designblock',
    name: 'Design Block',
   component: Design
}, 
{
    path: '/designblock/title',
    name: 'Title',
    component: title
 }
```